# Securing same endpoint with multiple configurations

Tags: spring, spring-security

We have a microservice architecture with securities for front to back with JWT, and back-to-back security with HTTP Basic.

Here is our configuration class for JWT :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers(endpointsProperties.getJwtWithWildcard())
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().addFilterBefore(jwtFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

jwtFilter is a simple filter that reads the Authorization header, and set the SecurityContextHolder.

And the HTTP Basic :

```
@Override
public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    for (Map<String, String> userData : properties.getUsers()) {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                .withUser(userData.get("login")).password(userData.get("password")).authorities(BASIC_AUTH_AUTHORITY);
    }


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers().antMatchers(endpoints.getBasicWithWildcard() )
            .and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().httpBasic();
}
```

Those configuration class are used in differnets services, with distinct JWT and HTTP Auth endpoints. They are used either at the same time or independently. EndpointsProperties are loaded from application.yml.

But now, we have some referential microservices that we want to be reached either by other services or direclty by a (web) frontend application. We want to know if it is possible to secure a same URL ('/api/referential', for example) with the two different methods. Combining those configuration class with the same endpoints does not work, and it seems one configuration eraze the other.

Is it possible to secure a same URL path with different methods like that ? If yes, what do we need to change to enable it ?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add the two filters to the filter chain in this order

1. BasicAuthenticationFilter
2. JwtFilter

and make sure the `ignoreFailure` property of the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` is set to `true`.

This will make The basicAuthFilter authenticate requests with basicAuth and just continue down the filter chain if no basicAuth is sent - thus delegating to the JwtFilter.

then remove `.httpBasic()` from the `WebsecurityConfig` - as it will try to add another BasicSecurityFilter.

Just an off the cuff idea